# Why is the Centripetal Force Positive, if the acceleration is negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, vectors, centripetal-force

If $ma_r = F $, but F is positive and $a_r$ is negative, wouldn't this mean a negative mass? I understand why centripetal acceleration is or is defined to be negative, since it is in the opposite direction of the radial vector, but then shouldn't the force also be negative. Also, what exactly is accelerating with centripetal acceleration, i.e. how is an object moving around on a circular path accelerating towards the center?

Comment: It would mean that you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Newton's 2nd law, which you showed, is a vector relationship,
$$\vec F=m\vec a.$$
Mathematically, the $\vec F$ vector and the $\vec a$ vector are parallel and in the same direction. Thus, your resulting force cannot point oppositely to your resulting acceleration - they will always point the same way.

In circular motion, an inwards force - such as gravity on a satellite - is pulling and causing a likewise inwards acceleration - which is why the satellite turns and thus orbits about the Earth. They point in the same direction. The choice of coordinate system doesn't matter, so you could easily define "inwards / towards the centre" as negative as you mention. Then both the force and the centripetal acceleration just have to be negative.

To understand what centripetal acceleration is, think of the satellite example I just gave. Or maybe think of a game of tetherball. When you hit the ball, then the ball "wants to" fly off in a straight line. But the string pulls inwards. This causes the ball to turn. Since the velocity vector is changing, then an acceleration is present - the velocity vector is changing by turning inwards, meaning that the acceleration must inwards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about how you define the forces for a rotating system. Suppose you are whirling a stone around at the end of a rope:

[image: Stone on rope]

There is a tension $T$ in the rope given by:

$$ T = mr\omega^2 $$

At your hand the tension pulls outwards i.e. in the positive $r$ direction, so at your hand there is an outwards force:

$$ F_1 = + mr\omega^2 $$

And where the rope connects to the stone it exerts an inwards force:

$$ F_2 = - mr\omega^2 $$

We call the force $F_2$ the *centripetal* force because it acts inwards towards the centre, and the force $F_1$ acting on your hand is a *centrifugal* force because it acts outwards.

The centripetal and centrifugal forces have equal magnitudes but opposite signs because they act in opposite directions.